# Joomla & PHP 7 : Fatal error: Argument 1 passed to JErrorPage::render()

Tags: php, joomla, php-7, php-7.2

Got the following error when I try to update a Joomla 3.9 website on a PHP7.2 environement.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to JErrorPage::render() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given in /var/www/xxxxx/libraries/cms/error/page.php:28 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: JErrorPage::render(Object(Error)) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/xxxxx/libraries/cms/error/page.php on line 28

Any idea what could cause this?

Website works fine on PHP 5.6 but I can't switch to PHP 7.2

Comment: JoomlaStackExchange hasn't seen you for nearly a year.  Perhaps post your question over there.